# Writing multiline JTextArea content into file

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, filewriter, jtextcomponent

I have to write the content of textarea into a file with line breaks. I got the output like, it is written as one string in the file.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {

text.setVisible(true);
String str= text.getText();
System.out.println(str);

try {
    BufferedWriter fileOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("filename.txt")); 


    fileOut.write(str);

    fileOut.close();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Example

Output should be:

```
I
am
King.
```

but it is showing:

```
IamKing.
```

Please get me some suggestions

Comment: I suspect you use notepad to view the output. Try, before writing, converting all newlines: `str.replaceAll("\n", "\r\n");`

Comment: `text.setVisible(true);` This field should already be visible!

Answer (score 6):

Use [`JTextComponent.write(Writer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write%28java.io.Writer%29):

> Stores the contents of the model into the given stream. By default this will store the model as plain text.

### E.G.

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("filename.txt"));
text.write(writer);
```