# saving file in same format as textarea prob

Tags: java, swing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Writing multiline JTextArea content into file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438104/writing-multiline-jtextarea-content-into-file)

i have written  code that save file from my text area the problem is that it saves it all on a single line in the new text file and not as in my text box.below are my codes

```
    String text = dna_ta.getText();

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory( new File( "./") );
    int actionDialog = chooser.showSaveDialog(this);
    if (actionDialog == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        BufferedWriter out = null;
        try {
            File fileName = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile( ) + "" );
            if(fileName == null)
                return;
            if(fileName.exists())
            {
                actionDialog = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,
                                   "Replace existing file?");
                if (actionDialog == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
                    return;
            }
            out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
            out.write(text);
            out.close();
```

in my text area is it as follows

```
 asd
 aaaaaa
```

but in my save textfile it is as follows

```
 asdaaaaaa
```

i cant figure out where i have gone wrong to save it as same format as in my textarea.thank you

Comment: Note that I removed the [tag:netbeans] tag and added the [tag:swing] tag as this question has nothing to do with NetBeans and all to do with Swing and IO.

Answer (score 4):

You could just use the JTextArea's `write(...)` method to do this for you:

```
out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
dna_ta.write(out);
out.close(); // after first checking if null
```

All components that derive from JTextComponent, including JTextArea, have this method which will write new lines using OS specific new line characters.